# How to add a column to a dataframe from another dataframe with different size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes and I want to add a new column to one of my dataframes from another dataframe 
'''

```
(df1)                            
Id   height  ...                 
12   190
13   180
34   173
```

.
.
.

```
(df2)
Id     amount  ...
12      234
15      256
13      248
```

.
.
.

'''
how can I add a column "amount" to df1 that contains the value amount of df2 for each Id of df1. the size of df1 and df2 are not equal

Comment: `df.join(df1.set_index('Id'), on='Id')`

Answer (score 2):

You can [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the two DataFrames on the `Id` column and then assign the resulting `amount` column to your first df:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Id": [12, 13, 34], "height": [1, 2, 3]}
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Id": [12, 15, 13], "amount": [4, 5, 6]}
)

df1["amount"] = df1.merge(df2, on="Id")["amount"]
```

Result:

```
>>> print(df1)

   Id  height  amount
0  12       1     4.0
1  13       2     6.0
2  34       3     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Id Id is index column then you can use update method to do that

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[12, 190.0], [13, 180.0], [34, 173.0]], columns=('Id', 'height')).set_index("Id")

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[12, 234.0], [15, 256.0], [13, 248.0]], columns=('Id', 'amount')).set_index("Id")

df1["amount"] = np.nan
df1.update(df2, overwrite=True)
print(df1)
```

**Result**

```
    height  amount
Id                
12   190.0   234.0
13   180.0   248.0
34   173.0     NaN
```